# Routers with decent parental monitoring / traffic logging?

Tags: monitoring, logging, firmware, parental-controls, router

I'm looking for **consumer** router / firmware recommendations with reasonably robust remote URL / hostname logging & reporting functionality.

Most logging functionality I've seen is terrible - reporting only IP addresses, not rolling up reports or reporting any useful statistics. The logs are also often limited to merely the last few minutes/hours when handling high-traffic loads.

*Bonus points for providing a screenshot of the log reporting interface!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use several different routers with the [DD-WRT](http://dd-wrt.com/) router firmware (List of supported devices [here](http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices). For examples of some of the logging options you have, check out [this](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Using_RFlow_Collector_and_MySQL_To_Gather_Traffic_Information) wiki article. It does include a screenshot, but the data actually is stored in a mysql database on your PC, so I think the time that you can log will be pretty large, depending on how much space you are willing to sacrifice.

> You can have your DD-WRT router send traffic information to a PC on your network and then store the information in a MySQL database that you can search. This can tell you a lot about the traffic on your network.

Comment: go ahead and edit your post and include any links that are relevant, they will get converted shortly be those who can edit

Comment: @heavyd - Thanks for the up, added some more helpful links.

Comment: This solution is overkill compared to what I was looking for: *perfect*.

Comment: 11 years passed. The solution and even the hyperlinks still work!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you need the right tool, not the right router. If your router supports SNMP you can use any one of a bazillion tools to poll it. I like [PRTG](http://www.paessler.com/prtg) myself.

Comment: It seems, for using SNMP monitoring tools, one needs a server and software installed on every device. Some tools (e.g., Kaseya) are agentless (no need for software on the monitored devices), but it seems it would still need a server (a computer running 24/7) to actually do the job of monitoring. Honestly, a capable router to me looks like a more attractive solution.